# Wikipedia API redirect request

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am using the Wikipedia API by queries like these
[action=query&prop=extracts&format=jsonfm&exintro=&titles=CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=jsonfm&exintro=&titles=CSS)

Unlike the Wikipedia webpage, this does not automatically redirect to Cascading style sheets. I would like it to do so. Is there a way to do the same in the request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`redirects`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=CSS) parameter: [action=query&prop=extracts&format=jsonfm&exintro=&titles=CSS&redirects](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=jsonfm&exintro=&titles=CSS&redirects)